# "ModelState.IsValid" is failing for navigation key with message "field is required" in ASP.NET Core with EF Core and Razor Pages

Tags: asp.net-core, validation, entity-framework-core, razor-pages

I am building an ASP.NET Core application for managing Orders of the Customers. Here, I am using EF Core and Razor Pages.

The model classes for the entities are **Order** and **Customer**.

Order class (Order.cs):

```
public class Order
{
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public string OrderNumber { get; set; }
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }

    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
}
```

Customer class (Customer.cs):

```
public class Customer
{
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}
```

DbContext class (MyDbContext.cs):

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; } = default!;
    public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; } = default!;
}
```

Razor Page for creating orders (Orders.cshtml):

```
@page
@model OrdersModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Orders";
}

<h1>Orders</h1>

<form method="post">
    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Order.OrderNumber" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="Order.OrderNumber" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Order.OrderNumber" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Order.Customer" class="control-label"></label>
        <select asp-for="Order.CustomerId" asp-items="ViewBag.CustomerId" class="form-control"></select>
        <span asp-validation-for="Order.CustomerId" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </div>    
</form>
```

Razor Page's code-behind file (Orders.cshtml.cs):

```
public class OrdersModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly MyDbContext _dbContext;

    public OrdersModel(MyDbContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    [BindProperty]
    public Order Order { get; set; } = default!;

    public IActionResult OnGet()
    {
        ViewData["CustomerId"] = new SelectList(_dbContext.Customer, "CustomerId", "Name");
        return Page();
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid || _context.Order == null || Order == null)
        {
            return Page();
        }

        _dbContext.Order.Add(Order);
        await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

        return RedirectToPage("./Index");
    }
}
```

Mostly, I am using the scaffolded code in Razor Pages.

But, on executing the code, I am getting validation error.

On debugging, it is found that `ModelState.IsValid` is failing for navigation key with message "field is required" for ASP.NET Core application with EF Core and Razor Pages. .

Surprisingly, removing the validity check `ModelState.IsValid` submits the form and records the data into the database perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

From your model design in `Order`, The `Customer` property is an Optional reference navigation, It will not map to the column in table. So even you don't give any value to this property you can also insert data into database correctly.

Prior to .NET 6, new projects do not include the Nullable element. Beginning with .NET 6, new projects include the `<Nullable>enable</Nullable>` element in the project file.

The `Customer` property is non-nullable(Equivalent to hermit adding a [Required] property) by default, So if you don't bind any value to this property, ModelState.IsValid will return false.

If you don't want this, you can disable this by deleting the below line from the csproj file or setting it as disable. By default(.Net 6) value is enable.

```
<Nullable>enable</Nullable>
```

Or, you can just add ? to make it nullable:

```
public Customer? Customer { get; set; }
```

Or, make ModelState ignore this property:

```
if (ModelState.Remove("Customer"))
{
      *save form, go somewhere*
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The technical explanation is that your model includes non-nullable properties that are null when you call ModelState.IsValid.

EF Core is fine with the null values because it know that it will create those values when data is inserted into the database.

However, the root of your problem is that you are using a single class to try and satisfy both EF Core and your Posts.

I know it sounds like duplication of work, but the proper way is to define a set of classes for submissions of posts and a set of classes for defining the data in EF Core.

For example, when submitting to a Post you don't need to provide an Id or a Customer object.  Therefore the model that is used for submitting to a Post should not include them:

You want something like:

```
OrderPostDto
{
    public string OrderNumber { get; set; }
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
}
```

to be submitted to the Post.

Then in your Post method:

```
[BindProperty]
public OrderPostDto OrderModel { get; set; } = default!;

public IActionResult OnGet()
{
    ViewData["CustomerId"] = new SelectList(_dbContext.Customer, "CustomerId", "Name");
    return Page();
}

public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return Page();
    }

    Order orderEF = new Order()
    {
        OrderNumber = OrderModel.OrderNumber,
        CustomerId = OrderModel.CustomerId
    }

    _dbContext.Order.Add(orderEF);
    await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

    return RedirectToPage("./Index");
}
```