# Using .NET 8 in my ASP.NET Core project and learning EF Core, how do you properly update a row / record of a database table

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am trying to get into ASP.NET and I followed this [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-rp/intro?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio) so far.

I didn't just copy everything but wanted to apply the knowledge to my own little idea of a football (soccer) prediction app. But first things first.

There are two model classes: the `Team` which holds information about a team:

```
public class Team
{
    [Key]
    public int TeamID { get; set; }

    public string? Name { get; set; }

    public string? Abbreviation { get; set; }

    public string? Emblem { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("HomeTeam")]
    public ICollection<Match> MatchesAsHomeTeam { get; set; } = new HashSet<Match>();

    [InverseProperty("GuestTeam")]
    public ICollection<Match> MatchesAsGuestTeam { get; set; } = new HashSet<Match>();
}
```

and the `Match` which holds information about a match. Each match is associated with exactly two teams. So there are two parallel one-to-many relationships between these two entities.

```
public class Match
{
    [Key]
    public int MatchID { get; set; }

    public int? HomeScore { get; set; }
    public int? GuestScore { get; set; }

    public DateTime? KickOff { get; set; }

    public int HomeTeamID { get; set; }
    public Team HomeTeam { get; set; }

    public int GuestTeamID { get; set; }
    public Team GuestTeam { get; set; }
}
```

I am still learning and testing and for this reason I am using `EnsureCreated()` to create the database.

The `DbContext` class looks like this:

```
public class TeamContext : DbContext
{
    public TeamContext (DbContextOptions<TeamContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<BundesligaTipp.Models.Team> Teams { get; set; } = default!;
    public DbSet<BundesligaTipp.Models.Match> Matches { get; set; } = default!;

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Team>().ToTable(nameof(Team));
        modelBuilder.Entity<Match>().ToTable(nameof(Match));

        modelBuilder.Entity<Match>()
                    .HasOne(match => match.HomeTeam)
                    .WithMany(team => team.MatchesAsHomeTeam)
                    .HasForeignKey(match => match.HomeTeamID)
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientCascade);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Match>()
                    .HasOne<Team>(match => match.GuestTeam)
                    .WithMany(team => team.MatchesAsGuestTeam)
                    .HasForeignKey(match => match.GuestTeamID)
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientCascade);
    }
}
```

As you can see, I am using the fluent API to set up the navigational properties. I hope I did it correctly. But from what I tested it seems to work.

Additionally, I let the corresponding Razor pages (CRUD) be scaffolded and pages associated with the `Team` model work perfectly fine but I have a problem with the Edit page for the match model. So initially Create didn't work because the `ModelState.IsValid` failed due to the navigation properties `HomeTeam` and `GuestTeam` not explicitly set while by design not allowing null values. I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76542033/modelstate-isvalid-is-failing-for-navigation-key-with-message-field-is-requir) yesterday and accordingly I created a class that just takes in the IDs for `HomeTeam` and `GuestTeam`.

With this the Create pages works.

Now, I wanted to apply the same solution to the Edit page, which suffered from the same problem. But I cannot get it to work as I stumbled over a different problem. I tinkered with the PageModel and this is the current version.

```
public class MatchEdit
{
    public int? HomeScore { get; set; }
    public int? GuestScore { get; set; }
    public DateTime? KickOff { get; set; }
}

public class EditModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly BundesligaTipp.Data.TeamContext _context;

    public EditModel(BundesligaTipp.Data.TeamContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    [BindProperty]
    public MatchEdit MatchDummy { get; set; } = default!;

    public Match Match { get; set; } = default!;

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var match =  await _context.Matches.FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.MatchID == id);
        if (match == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        Match = match;
        return Page();
    }

    // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to.
    // For more details, see https://aka.ms/RazorPagesCRUD.
    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return Page();
        }

        if(MatchDummy.KickOff != null)
            Match.KickOff = MatchDummy.KickOff;

        if(MatchDummy.HomeScore != null)
            Match.HomeScore = MatchDummy.HomeScore;

        if(MatchDummy.GuestScore != null)
            Match.GuestScore = MatchDummy.GuestScore;
            
        
        if(MatchDummy.KickOff != null || MatchDummy.HomeScore != null || MatchDummy.GuestScore != null)
            _context.Attach(Match).State = EntityState.Modified;
        else
            _context.Attach(Match).State = EntityState.Unchanged;

        try
        {
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            if (!MatchExists(Match.MatchID))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return RedirectToPage("./Index");
    }

    private bool MatchExists(int id)
    {
        return _context.Matches.Any(e => e.MatchID == id);
    }
}
```

The `ModelState.IsValid` test passes, but the instance of `Match` which is loaded in `OnGetAsync` is stored in the `Match` variable (which I checked is true via Debugging), but later in `OnPostAsync` this variable is null and I get an error `NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` when assigning the properties from the bound object to the null object. The error makes sense, but I do not understand why the object is null in the first place.

So my questions are:

1. Why does the `Match` variable not keep that reference.
2. This PageModel generally looks very ugly. What is the proper way / best practice of constructing such a page?

Thank you very much!

EDIT:

Thanks to @Steve Py 's answer I made my code work. To everyone wondering why I used `attach`: I don't, most of the `PageModel` was created automatically by the scaffolding, including everything in the `try-catch` block. The only thing I really changed was introducing the `MatchEdit` class and the corresponding instance as `[BindPorperty]`

This is how the `PageModel` looks now:

```
public class MatchEdit
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? HomeScore { get; set; }
    public int? GuestScore { get; set; }
    public DateTime? KickOff { get; set; }
}

public class EditModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly BundesligaTipp.Data.TeamContext _context;

    public EditModel(BundesligaTipp.Data.TeamContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    [BindProperty]
    public MatchEdit MatchDummy { get; set; } = default!;

    public int id;

    public IActionResult OnGet(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        this.id = (int)id;

        return Page();
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(MatchEdit MatchDummy)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return Page();
        }

        var match = _context.Matches.Single(m => m.MatchID == MatchDummy.Id);

        if(MatchDummy.KickOff != null)
            match.KickOff = MatchDummy.KickOff;

        if(MatchDummy.HomeScore != null)
            match.HomeScore = MatchDummy.HomeScore;

        if(MatchDummy.GuestScore != null)
            match.GuestScore = MatchDummy.GuestScore;

        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return RedirectToPage("./Index");
    }
}
```

I added an `Id` property to the `MatchEdit` class and the `id` of the to-be-updated object is posted via a hidden form like this:

`<input type="hidden" value="@Model.id" asp-for="MatchDummy.Id" />`

`OnPostAsync` is exactly as suggested.

Comment: You should probably check the [Razor Pages with Entity Framework Core in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-rp/intro?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio) tutorial. The code is a lot simpler than what you're trying to do

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos This is exactly the guide I mentioned and linked ;)

Comment: That guide doesn't show the code you posted. Most of the configuration isn't needed, it's the same as EF's conventions. The tutorial doesn't use `Attach` either, it uses `Add` or `Update` instead. And that `MatchExists` contradicts the concurrency guidance entirely. `DbUpdateConcurrencyException` is only raised if some other request/user/connection tries to modify the same row you were modifying. By definition, that Match object already exists, so `MatchExists` serves no purpuse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be mixing examples and are doing a fair bit more than is needed and this is likely causing issues. The first thing would be to do away with the entity module level references inside the the models. If you use view models like MatchEdit to relay values that have changed, that is a good design as it doesn't expose your system to revealing too much and risking tampering.

The next thing is understanding how web applications with MVC and/or Razor pages work. When a GET request comes in you call View() optionally passing a model to the view. That call does not go to the client browser, it goes to the view engine on the server which builds the HTML going to the client browser. When the client calls a POST back to the server, those model references and such are not persisted, nor should you attempt to persist them (with things like `static` or Singleton lifetime scope references. You don't want references shared between different user requests and as soon as you introduce load balancing, the responding web server will likely not be the same instance that is keeping state in memory.

So instead in a POST method it should receive the view model being edited, then retrieve the matching entity, copying the values across:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(MatchEdit matchDummy)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return Page();

    var match = _context.Matches.Single(x => x.MatchId = matchDummy.MatchId);

    if(matchDummy.KickOff != null)
        match.KickOff = matchDummy.KickOff;

    if(matchDummy.HomeScore != null)
        match.HomeScore = matchDummy.HomeScore;

    if(matchDummy.GuestScore != null)
        match.GuestScore = matchDummy.GuestScore;
        
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    return RedirectToPage("./Index");
}
```

This will mean adding the Match ID to the view model being passed. Basically anything you send in the POST has to come from the client browser, so parsed from the HTML, assume nothing is going to be available server-side. Web applications don't pass references back and forth, it may look like that in code at times but each POST etc. is merely a populated copy.

Web applications should act in a stateless fashion where the server does not attempt to maintain state between requests as you won't necessarily know when a session actually ends. I.e. a user could just close their browser at any point. Sessions will time out, but the more you try to rely on server state the more issues you will encounter.

By default when a DbContext loads an entity, it will be a tracked instance so as you make changes it will be able to build an UPDATE SQL statement if values have actually changed. So there is no need to attempt to attach it or set entity state, that is likely what is causing some of the errors you are seeing, or stuff getting mixed up with the module level references. Just load the entity, update the fields, and call `SaveChanges`.

Comment: Thanks! I edited my post including you suggestion. Is the way I transfer the `id` to the object good practice? Is there a better way?

Comment: Including a meaningless ID is fine, as it is the act of retrieving that entity by ID that can assert things like that the row actually exists and whether the user logged into that session can access that row. (for instance in the case of a multi-tenant system) Passing meaningful IDs, such as something like a person's SIN/TFN, driver's licence #, or a Badge # would be bad. (I mean one should never use information like this as a PK even if it should be guaranteed to be unique. :)